# Read Null terminated string in python

Tags: python, scripting

I'm trying to read a null terminated string but i'm having issues when unpacking a char and putting it together with a string.

This is the code:

```
def readString(f):
    str = ''
    while True:
        char = readChar(f)
        str = str.join(char)
        if (hex(ord(char))) == '0x0':
            break           
    return str

def readChar(f):
    char = unpack('c',f.read(1))[0]
    return char
```

Now this is giving me this error:

```
TypeError: sequence item 0: expected str instance, int found
```

I'm also trying the following:

```
char = unpack('c',f.read(1)).decode("ascii")
```

But it throws me:
AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'decode'

I don't even know how to read the chars and add it to the string, Is there any proper way to do this?

Comment: With `str = str.join(char)`, did you intend `str += char`?

Comment: why you read 1 at the time?

Comment: Because i don't know the length, and i have to read until the byte is null, which is 0x00. And yes, i did intend that, but doing so throws me this error:

TypeError: Can't convert 'bytes' object to str implicitly

Comment: Then maybe you should decode the byte...

Comment: ok, then what kind of file is `f` then? and how you open it? if it is the typical file then there are better ways if want you a line or the whole content you use .readline or .read, as usually the null byte mark the end of the file those method read until that point. Also what python are you using? there are some differences between py2 and py3 that can affect the use of strings in each one

Comment: It's a Binary file that sepparates the strings between null bytes, which is why i'm doing that condition.

I don't think readline or .read works on these cases since it's not a text file, that's why i made up this thing.

I'm also using the python from Blender, which if i remember correctly is 2.7

Comment: I don't know how i can attach fileshere, but basically, it would be something like in this picture.

http://i.imgur.com/uNLicEt.png

You can see there are words in the binary file separated by 00 bytes.

Comment: well you could simple put the link...

Comment: Alright, i uploaded it in a puush. https://puu.sh/s1njo/496aa16d45.blendscn

Here is the thing: You first read a string of an unknown size which is the object in the blender scene, then you read the name of the parent, which you won't ever know the size either in the string, and then you read. and then you read another Data which contains the transformation matrix of the model, which, that is static, but if you read the same amount of bytes all the time, it might work in this file, but it may not if the name of the objects have a different string size. I don't know if it's more clear now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(edit version 2, added extra way at the end)

Maybe there are some libraries out there that can help you with this, but as I don't know about them lets attack the problem at hand with what we know.

In python 2 bytes and string are basically the same thing, that change in python 3 where string is what in py2 is unicode and bytes is its own separate type, which mean that you don't need to define a read char if you are in py2 as no extra work is required, so I don't think you need that `unpack` function for this particular case, with that in mind lets define the new `readString`

```
def readString(myfile):
    chars = []
    while True:
        c = myfile.read(1)
        if c == chr(0):
            return "".join(chars)
        chars.append(c)
```

just like with your code I read a character one at the time but I instead save them in a list, the reason is that string are immutable so doing str+=char result in unnecessary copies; and when I find the null character return the join string. And [`chr`](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/functions.html#chr) is the inverse of [`ord`](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/functions.html#ord), it will give you the character given its ascii value. This will exclude the null character, if its needed just move the appending...

Now lets test it with your [sample file](https://puu.sh/s1njo/496aa16d45.blendscn)

for instance lets try to read "Sword_Wea_Dummy" from it

```
with open("sword.blendscn","rb") as archi:
    #lets simulate that some prior processing was made by 
    #moving the pointer of the file
    archi.seek(6) 
    string=readString(archi)
    print "string repr:", repr(string)
    print "string:", string
    print ""
    #and the rest of the file is there waiting to be processed
    print "rest of the file: ", repr(archi.read())
```

and this is the output

```
string repr: 'Sword_Wea_Dummy'
string: Sword_Wea_Dummy

rest of the file:  '\xcd\xcc\xcc=p=\x8a4:\xa66\xbfJ\x15\xc6=\x00\x00\x00\x00\xeaQ8?\x9e\x8d\x874$-i\xb3\x00\x00\x00\x00\x9b\xc6\xaa2K\x15\xc6=;\xa66?\x00\x00\x00\x00\xb8\x88\xbf@\x0e\xf3\xb1@ITuB\x00\x00\x80?\xcd\xcc\xcc=\x00\x00\x00\x00\xcd\xccL>'
```

other tests

```
>>> with open("sword.blendscn","rb") as archi:
        print readString(archi)
        print readString(archi)
        print readString(archi)


sword
Sword_Wea_Dummy
ÍÌÌ=p=Š4:¦6¿JÆ=
>>> with open("sword.blendscn","rb") as archi:
        print repr(readString(archi))
        print repr(readString(archi))
        print repr(readString(archi))


'sword'
'Sword_Wea_Dummy'
'\xcd\xcc\xcc=p=\x8a4:\xa66\xbfJ\x15\xc6='
>>>
```

---

Now that I think about it, you mention that the data portion is of fixed size, if that is true for all files and the structure on all of them is as follow

```
[unknow size data][know size data]
```

then that is a pattern we can exploit, we only need to know the size of the file and we can get both part smoothly as follow

```
import os

def getDataPair(filename,knowSize):
    size = os.path.getsize(filename)
    with open(filename, "rb") as archi:
        unknown = archi.read(size-knowSize)
        know    = archi.read()
        return unknown, know
```

and by knowing the size of the data portion, its use is simple (which I get by playing with the prior example)

```
>>> strins_data, data = getDataPair("sword.blendscn", 80)
>>> string_data, data = getDataPair("sword.blendscn", 80)
>>> string_data
'sword\x00Sword_Wea_Dummy\x00'
>>> data
'\xcd\xcc\xcc=p=\x8a4:\xa66\xbfJ\x15\xc6=\x00\x00\x00\x00\xeaQ8?\x9e\x8d\x874$-i\xb3\x00\x00\x00\x00\x9b\xc6\xaa2K\x15\xc6=;\xa66?\x00\x00\x00\x00\xb8\x88\xbf@\x0e\xf3\xb1@ITuB\x00\x00\x80?\xcd\xcc\xcc=\x00\x00\x00\x00\xcd\xccL>'
>>> string_data.split(chr(0))
['sword', 'Sword_Wea_Dummy', '']
>>>
```

Now to get each string a simple split will suffice and you can pass the rest of the file contained in `data` to the appropriated function to be processed

Comment: The problem is that that was an example that had no ints, but my issue is that i have another data between the strings and the size of those strings is unknown, i do only know when i read a string in the data, but i don't know when i will end, which is why i am trying to do that kind of code. I probably explained myself badly and the image was a bad example, if i can't figure it out i'll put this one as a valid answer.

Comment: I am pretty sure that if you open the file that I make in this example with whatever you use you will see those numbers...

Comment: so you have some data first then with some marker you start reading those string? fine something can be done about that, you read those string until some other marker? or until the end of the file? if the later this solution is still valid if the pointer in the file is in the right position, read will give you everything from that point until the end of the file. If you read until some mark something can be done too

Comment: I read that string until the byte is null, and then i will read stuff like floats, ints, etc. and then I may read a string at some point again, since it's for blender, the string stands for the name of the object in the scene, so the size may vary and i might read the rest of the values wrong if i read an additional byte or i miss one. I managed to do this in a previous version of Python in 3DS Max with str+= char, but for some reason, in blender's version, it does not work.

Comment: I see, in that case your code is pretty close, lets make some adjustment

Comment: Blender seems to crash with this, but is not a wrong solution, and it helps with different programs, so this case will work, thanks a lot :).

Comment: I added other way, that don't involve reading 1 character at the time

Comment: While that is valid, what i send you is a small version of what i'm reading, so there are too many uknown portions of it to do that, but it's also a valid choice!

Comment: the number of unknowns is irrelevant as long as the known part is the last one, you can always make function that specialize in each part; but if the known part is between unknowns that is where the fun is, after all getting the known part is always easy...

Answer (score 9):

How about:

```
myString = myNullTerminatedString.split("\x00")[0]
```

For example:

```
myNullTerminatedString = "hello world\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00"
myString = myNullTerminatedString.split("\x00")[0]
print(myString) # "hello world"
```

This works by splitting the string on the null character. Since the string should terminate at the first null character, we simply grab the first item in the list after splitting. `split` will return a list of one item if the delimiter doesn't exist, so it still works even if there's no null terminator at all.

It also will work with byte strings:

```
myByteString = b'hello world\x00'
myStr = myByteString.split(b'\x00')[0].decode('ascii') # "hello world" as normal string
```

If you're reading from a file, you can do a relatively larger read - estimate how much you'll need to read to find your null string. This is a lot faster than reading byte-by-byte. For example:

```
resultingStr = ''
while True:
    buf = f.read(512)
    resultingStr += buf
    if len(buf)==0: break
    if (b"\x00" in resultingStr):
        extraBytes = resultingStr.index(b"\x00")
        resultingStr = resultingStr.split(b"\x00")[0]
        break
# now "resultingStr" contains the string

f.seek(0 - extraBytes,1) # seek backwards by the number of bytes, now the pointer will be on the null byte in the file
# or f.seek(1 - extraBytes,1) to skip the null byte in the file
```

Answer (score 7):

Here's a version that (ab)uses __iter__'s lesser-known "sentinel" argument:

```
with open('file.txt', 'rb') as f:
    val = ''.join(iter(lambda: f.read(1).decode('ascii'), '\x00'))
```

Comment: Reading one byte at a time is slow. Worse, you'll mangle any UTF-8 that happens to be in there.

Answer (score 1):

Doing file I/O one character at a time is horribly slow.

Instead use readline0, now on pypi: https://pypi.org/project/readline0/ .  Or something like it.

In 3.x, there's a "newline" argument to open, but it doesn't appear to be as flexible as readline0.

Comment: Does this work with binary files?, it talks about null-terminated lines but i'm not sure if it's text-only

Comment: Yes, in fact it's intended for binary files.

Answer (score -1):

Here is my implementation:

```
import struct

def read_null_str(f):
 r_str = ""
    
    while 1:
        back_offset = f.tell()
        try:
            r_char = struct.unpack("c", f.read(1))[0].decode("utf8")
        except:
            f.seek(back_offset)
            temp_char = struct.unpack("<H", f.read(2))[0]
            r_char = chr(temp_char)
        if ord(r_char) == 0:
            return r_str
        else:
            r_str += r_char
```